# Is there a way to highlight failed cells in an excel VBA script?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

Is there a way to highlight failed cells in an excel VBA script? It sends an email in outlook but when it can't find the corresponding name from my sheet in the outlook address book it just skips that row it and manual checking isn't realy an option since my excel sheet already contains more than 500 rows. Can I somehow add a line to highlight these rows where the address wasn't correct?

Comment: Without sharing the code you use, it is very difficult to receive a suggestion. Otherwise, it would be not complicated to receive suggestions to adapt your existing code. I can help, but only in these circumstances...

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the background colour e.g.`MyCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow`? (assuming here that MyCell is the "failing" cell encountered in your VBA processing).

Answer (score 0):

A quick search gave me this function:

```
Function CheckAddressExists(eAddress As String) As Boolean
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olContactFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olContact As Outlook.ContactItem
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim bFound As Boolean, bStarted As Boolean
On Error Resume Next

Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    bStarted = True
End If

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olContactFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(10)
Set olItems = olContactFolder.Items
For Each olContact In olItems
    bFound = False
    If eAddress = olContact.Email1Address Or _
       eAddress = olContact.Email2Address Or _
       eAddress = olContact.Email3Address Then
        bFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
    Err.Clear
Next olContact
If bFound Then
    CheckAddressExists = True
End If
CleanUp:
If bStarted = True Then
    olApp.Quit
End If
Set olItems = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olContactFolder = Nothing
Set olContact = Nothing
End Function
```

Supposedly in your loop that sends mails, you could check if the address exists by running it in this function first, and if it doesn't, highlight the address.

This code is untested by me, since I don't have a macro to send mails, and if you want help incorporating anything in what you have, you need to share the code you are using.